# The children are creating

Tags: meaning, british-english

In the lyrics of *Friends Will Be Friends* by *Queen*:

> Another red letter day
>   So the pound has dropped and **the children are creating**.

What does the phrase highlighted in bold mean?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Queen is a British band, and this usage of the intransitive *create* is British colloquial for "create a fuss", "make noise", or nearly, as ukayer says, "create havoc". The [*Compact Oxford Dictionary* has this](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/create?view=uk):

> 2 [*no object*] *British informal* make a fuss; complain:
>        *little kids create because they hate being ignored*

The [*Cambridge Advanced Learner's Dictionary* has this](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/create_2):

> **create** *verb* (BE ANGRY) /kriˈeɪt/
>     [I] UK *old-fashioned* to show that you are angry
>        *If she sees you with an ice cream she'll only start creating.*

The [*Collins Pocket English Dictionary* has this](http://www.collinslanguage.com/results.aspx?context=3&reversed=False&action=define&homonym=-1&text=create):

> 4. (Brit slang) to make an angry fuss,

[*Dictionary.com*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/Create?r=66) (based on [*Random House*](http://dictionary.infoplease.com/create) dictionary) has this:

> –*verb (used without object)*
>   8. *British*. to make a fuss.

The [*Collins English Dictionary — Complete and Unabridged*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/create) also has this:

> 6. *(intr) Brit slang* to make a fuss or uproar

See also [this post by lynneguist](http://separatedbyacommonlanguage.blogspot.com/2009/04/to-create-intransitive.html) on *Separated By a Common Language*, where I first encountred the term. It's used mostly for little children (or those considered little children), rather than adults.

Comment: I guess this answer should have started with "Queen *are* a British band".

Answer (score 2):

Creating as in "creating havoc", i.e. helping to make the day even worse.

Comment: May I ask how you know that that's what that means?

Comment: That's just my interpretation of the lyric.  In Britain, you might such a phrase as "the children are creating" with the listener left to interpret the phrase as "creating havoc" based on the context.  You'd have to read the entire lyric not just the line in question.